import 'exported' sql file into mysql database using node.js
I had one sql file which i want to import in my new database using node.js.
I have tried multiple ways but no progress
This error i receive when i try readFile approach

Error executing SQL file: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE attendance (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
date date DEFAULT NU...' at line 62

const newPool = mySql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.ORGANIZATION_HOST,
        user: process.env.ORGANIZATION_USER,
        password: process.env.ORGANIZATION_PASS,
        database: subDName,
        port: process.env.ORGANIZATION_PORT,
        connectionLimit: 10,
        charset: "utf8mb4",
        connectTimeout: 60000,
        acquireTimeout: 60000,
      });

      // Connect to MySQL
      newPool.connect((err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });

      executeSqlFromFile(newPool, "dbmain.sql")
        .then(() => {
          console.log("SQL file executed successfully");
          dbPool.end();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error executing SQL file:", error);
          dbPool.end();
        });

//Import Function
function executeSqlFromFile(pool, filePath) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (err, sqlCommands) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
    return;
  }

  // Execute SQL commands as a single query
  pool.query(sqlCommands, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
      return;
    }
    console.log("SQL file executed successfully");
    resolve(results);
  });
 });
});
}

//SQL File
 CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `punch_in_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `punch_out_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_mail` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attendance_status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `break_count` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `break_in_status` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `break_out_status` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `break_details` longtext DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

